# How can i change form-check(Radio button ) to 5 points slider in HTML/JS page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a survey page but i want to change survey question from radio button to 5 point slider.I try to use

```
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1"/>
```

But it is not working also i need to define each value with some text as i did below in my radio button code ..please help me with that and suggest the solution.I also want to get value from those slider as i did it in below code.

HTML :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Survey Question</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>

  </style>
  <section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Survey</h2>
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Section 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
          <div id="section1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
            <div class="section-1-questions">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="section-2-question">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="final-results"></div>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                            Show Results
                        </button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="control" style="display: none">
              <a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to
                                email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

JS :-

```
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
    document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
  }
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}
```

CSS:-

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .final-results * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .final-results {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use bootstrap-slider.js
I updated the code for one "*question*" only

[bootstrap-slider.js documentation](https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/)

CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/bootstrap- 
slider.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

HTML

```
<input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider- 
step="1" data-slider-value="0" /> <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider 
Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>
```

JQ

```
$("#ex6").slider();
$("#ex6").on("slide", function (slideEvt) {
$("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value); });
```

sample snippet

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
    document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
  }
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}
//slider code
$("#ex6").slider();
$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
  $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .final-results * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .final-results {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Survey Question</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <style>
    @media print {
      body * {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      .final-results * {
        visibility: visible;
      }
      .final-results {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }
    }
    
    table,
    table tr th,
    table tr td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Survey</h2>
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Section 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
          <div id="section1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
            <div class="section-1-questions">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0" />
                    <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span
                                                id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                                1
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                                2
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                                                3
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                                                1
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                                                2
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                                                3
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="section-2-question">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                                                1
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                                                2
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                                                3
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                                                1
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                                                2
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                                                3
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                                                1
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                                                2
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                                                3
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                                                1
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                                                2
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                                                3
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="final-results"></div>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                            Show Results
                        </button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="control" style="display: none">
              <a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to
                                email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to
                                PDF</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```